# Why does the form duplicates after removing one child div form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm a student and new to JavaScript and JQuery. I took some time to understand and learn (by myself) how to write a program using both PHP and JQuery for the program I am working on.

I try to allow users to add multiple forms by using an Add button and remove as well. My question is, why does the child form group duplicates after user removes the added form and how do I ensure that the 'select2' plugin initializes properly?

I wrote a sample for you to try it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/SeppuCake/mrf43e2d/7/).

HTML Code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pointsTitleDiv" class="form-group">
        <label for="pointsTitle" class="col-sm-3 control-label">PRODUCT</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control select2" id="pointsTitle" name="pointsTitle[]" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="">Select Product</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
            <span id="pointsTitleSpan" class="help-block" style="display:none"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pointsQuantityDiv" class="form-group">
        <label for="pointsQuantity" class="col-sm-3 control-label">QUANTITY</label>
        <div class="date col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control pull-right" id="pointsQuantity" name="pointsQuantity[]">
            <span id="pointsQuantitySpan" class="help-block" style="display:none"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="addButton" class="form-group-sm pull-right" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 10px">
            <button type="button" id="add" name="add" class="btn btn-info pull-right">ADD ORDER</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="childFormGroup" class="form-group" style="padding-left: 10px">

    </div>
    <!-- /.form group -->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //Initialize Select2 Elements
            $('.select2').select2()
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    //Counter for form addition
    var count = 1;
    //Defining buttons
    var addButton = document.getElementById("add");
    var removeButton = document.getElementsByName("remove");
    //VARIABLES
    var divID = "#pointsTitle";
    var html = '';
    var selectData = '<option value = "">Select Product</option><option value = "1">Option 1</option><option value = "2">Option 2</option>';
    var x = 0;

    //Populate select box for first form. 'selectData' replicates the data coming from a Database to populate the select option.
    $("#pointsTitle").html(selectData);

    //Add button's behaviour
    addButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

        html += '<div id = "childFormGroup-internal' + count + '"><hr>';
        html += '<div id = "childpointsTitleDiv' + count + '" class = "form-group" style = "padding-left: 5px">';
        html += '<label for="childpointsTitle" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><p> PRODUCT</p></label>';
        html += '<div class="date col-sm-4"><select class = "childselect' + count + ' form-control pull-right" id="pointsTitle' + count + '" name="pointsTitle[]" style="width: 100%;">';
        html += '<option value="">Select Order</option>';
        html += '</select><span id="childpointsTitleSpan' + count + '" class="help-block" style="display:none"></span>';
        html += '</div></div>';
        html += '<div id="childpointsQuantityDiv' + count + '" class="form-group" style = "padding-left: 5px"><label for="childpointsQuantity" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> QUANTITY</label><div class="date col-sm-4">';
        html += '<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control pull-right" id="pointsQuantity" name="pointsQuantity[]"><span id="childpointsQuantitySpan' + count + '" class="help-block" style="display:none"></span>';
        html += '</div><span class="pull-right" style = "padding-right: 40px; padding-top: 10px"><button type="button" id = "' + count + '" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></span></div></div>';

        $("#childFormGroup").html(html);

        for (x = 1; x <= count; x++) {
            $(".childselect" + x).select2();
            $(divID + x).html(selectData);
        }
        count++;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
        --count;
        --x;
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");

        $("#childFormGroup-internal" + button_id).remove();
    });

});
```

I am out of ideas. I appreciate your time and help in guiding me through this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you forms are getting duplicated is that you keep appending the form html to your `html` variable every time the `addButton` is clicked.

What you need to fix that is to define the `html` variable inside the click handler function so that it is empty before you add a form.

Then, you loop through all your forms and initialize select2 on these. But you actually need to initialize select2 only on those forms where it has not been initialized. So get the id for the form that you just appended and initialize select2 only for this form.

Instead of counting groups, you can use the `length` property. For example,

```
$( '[id^="childFormGroup-internal"]' ).length
```

This will get you the number of your forms on the page. Even better if you add a class to these forms, for example, .childFormGroup-internal, then you will be able to select even easier:

```
var count = $( '.childFormGroup-internal' ).length // goes in the click handler to be up to date with the number of the forms on the page at the time of the click
```

It also makes it easier to generate IDs for new forms:

```
var newId = count + 1
```

And to initialize select2 on new forms (outside any loop):

```
$(".childselect" + newId).select2();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This certainly helped me out with the duplication problem. However, there's a bug that I found. When the new forms were added, let's say 3 new forms added. If a user removes 1 form (leaving 2 forms), and adds to make 3 forms again, the select options aren't populated.

Here's the current modification that I made. 
https://jsfiddle.net/SeppuCake/mrf43e2d/20/
Sorry for the trouble and thank you so much for your help and time in advance.

Comment: I can see you have added some logging — and from it, you can see what is going on: when you remove a form, your counter is reset to 0. Watch your scope: you have redefined newId as a local variable of addButton click handler and you are trying to use it in the remove button click handler. But it uses the value defined in the document.ready scope.

Comment: In this case, I'll have to figure out how to transfer the value into the 'remove' button var in order for it to properly identify which form? Thanks again for your huge help.

Comment: I'll give you a hint. You do not need to re-define the variable, you just need to assign the value to it. You can use the newId variable defined in the outer scope of document.ready in both your functions, but if you define it with var, it becomes a different variable, local to the function where you defined it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your example. I don't know jQuery, but the first thing you should do is check whether the `count` variable has a proper value after each "add" or "remove" click. You can do this with the Javascript `alert()` function to give yourself a popup containing the value of `count`.

Also, why are you decrementing `x` in the "remove" code? That is supposed to be internal to your earlier `for` loop... I don't fully understand the code but I don't think you need to change that elsewhere.

Comment: I did print the 'count' through console.log() and as it adds & removes, it does increment & decrement each time the buttons were clicked. For the 'x' case, previously a friend of mine suggested me to test it out if it does any difference. Obviously that the 'for' loop declared that x =1 every time the function is invoked.